# ASP.NET MVC 4 - JQuery.removeClass Not Working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Im trying to have a class of my text box remove when a users inputs something but it doesnt seem to work. Heres the code for my text box and the function I'm using .

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-state-error" oninput="redo()" value="6"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function redo() {
        $("#name").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
</script>
```

I'm not quite seeing the problem here.. any suggestions?

Comment: This works for me, try adding `alert($("#name").attr('class'));` underneath the call to `removeClass`.

Comment: Hm! That removed the class indeed, but how can I make it update the textbox to show its been removed?

Comment: How would you like the change to be indicated? colouration, a change in text?

Comment: In the class, theres a background image that shows dashes, and a red border around it, I want it to be removed as soon as the user inputs. Basically resetting the textbox ya know?

Comment: Are you using jqueryUI also in your project ?

Answer (score 2):

when using `input`'s use `onfocus` (when someone click inside) or `onblur` (when someone click outside after being focused).

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-state-error" value="6"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).delegate("#name", "focus", function() {
        $("#name").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    });
</script>
```

here is a small working example: http://jsbin.com/udejuf/1/edit

---

by the way, if you use **jQuery Validation**, this will be handled for you automatically.

Example with jQuery Validate: http://jsbin.com/uxoqed/1/edit

Comment: "4 some reason" ... what example is not working? what browser are you using? What are you doing :)

Comment: what does the console log tell you? run it on Chrome Browser and press F12, then click in the Console tab. Are you loading the scripts in the correct order? What versions are you loading? Any change to create a simple page (just copy the generated HTML code) and placed in a example page so we can look at it?